# Building images on docker

Tags: docker

Can images in docker be installed by source code. What I mean is I want to build my environment with several components and their dependencies. I want to build the components by executing the source code. Does docker allow me to do something like that ?

Comment: Do you need a container (system) to compile or deploy the application? Could you precise your question? Make it clearer, please?

Comment: Why not just build the images and put them in a repository (ex: docker hub) then define the setup in, say, docker-compose file or a script that configures the whole docker stack, which you can include in your source code.

Comment: Actually docker is something we are trying out instead of a virtual machine  like VMware. The requirement is to build components over one another and then try to test dependencies. For the initial work done over this, all the components were built by executing the source code and not installing the exe or dmg file. So, I just want to know if there is a way to build components in the same manner in docker.

Comment: Also this is my first encounter with docker, so if you can recommend some tutoriasl for me to get more familiar with it, it would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want a dynamic docker build process. For this you need docker 1.9 up , use --build-args to pass argument variables . You can build multiple images from a single docker file passing in different argument values each time.

Obviously suffers the reproducibility issue discussed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it allows you to do that. You need to start with a base image. For example Ubuntu:

```
docker pull ubuntu
docker run -t -i ubuntu /bin/bash
```

After that you will have a bash running inside of your container. Then you can apt-get stuff, run code, change configurations, clone repos and whatever else you want. After that to convert your container into an image you need to [commit the container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/).

Be aware that this is not the Docker way of building infrastructure. The correct way is to create a recipe for building you images by using other base images and standard Docker instructions. This will allow your infrastructure to be stateless, faster to build and will provide more reproducibility.

Comment: A better way is to create a `Dockerfile` and build an image rather than `commit`-ting a modified image. Note also that I'm unsure whether or not it answers the _not-so-well-formulated_ question. (The `docker pull` is also optional as `docker run` will pull it automatically if not found locally).

Comment: You are totally right. This is why I say it is not the Docker way. It's a very dirty solution that makes images very hard to maintain, but this is what the question is asking.

Comment: -Auzias, I have explained the question thoroughly, I hope that can help you answer better.

Comment: - nstoitsev. Thanks for the answer. I have build the basefile already. So you mean inside the basefile container I can start building other images, for example i have to build a gnu compiler component on ubuntu so can I build it using the source code.